# T-SQL "dense_rank" with a maximum number of rows with each rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dense-rank

If I do a

```
dense_rank() over (order by colname),
```

I get the same rank for all rows with the same value in the column colname.

However, I want to limit the number of rows with the same rank to @maxrows so that when @maxrows rows have the same value in colname, a new rank is assigned to the next row even if the value of colname is still the same.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use Ntile function as the NTILE function allows you to associate the rows in the result with tiles (equally sized groups of
rows) by assigning a tile number to each row. You specify the number of tiles you are after as input
to the function, and in the OVER clause, you specify the logical ordering.

Comment: `NTILE` does almost the opposite of what the OP is asking for - you specify how many groups you want, not the size of the groups. In addition, `NTILE` would place rows with *different* `colname` values within the same group, which isn't at all like `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this via using several ranking functions. We use `ROW_NUMBER()` in the middle and another column to perform tie-breaking:

```
declare @maxRows int
set @maxRows = 5

; With InitialRanks as (
    select DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY type) as rnk,* from sys.objects
), OrderedRanks as (
    select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rnk ORDER by object_id)-1)
            / @maxRows as rn,*
    from InitialRanks
)
select DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rnk,rn),* from OrderedRanks
```

Here I get only up to 5 columns with each (final) rank value. The ranking is based on `type` but we use `object_id` as a secondary column to work out the order in which rows are allowed a particular rank.

---

Turns out I'd over-complicated the above - there's no need for the first CTE and the first `DENSE_RANK` since that's effectively acting as a proxy for the `type` column in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function - so why not just use the `type` column directly and simplify things:

```
declare @maxRows int
set @maxRows = 5

; With  OrderedRanks as (
    select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER by object_id)-1)
            / @maxRows as rn,*
    from sys.objects
)
select DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY type,rn),* from OrderedRanks
```

Comment: Very creative use of ranking functions!