# Assigning new group for every n records in each category

Tags: t-sql

I need to create groups for every n records in each categories. For example I have student table with StdId, Gender and Subject, now I want to divide all students in groups by their gender and subject and each group can not have more than two.

Here is code for sample data

```
declare @Students table (StdId int, Gender char(1), Subj varchar(10))

insert into @students select 1, 'F', 'Math'
insert into @students select 2, 'M', 'Math'
insert into @students select 3, 'M', 'Math'
insert into @students select 4, 'F', 'Math'
insert into @students select 5, 'F', 'Math'
insert into @students select 6, 'F', 'History'
insert into @students select 7, 'M', 'History'
insert into @students select 8, 'F', 'English'
insert into @students select 9, 'F', 'English'
insert into @students select 10, 'M', 'English'
insert into @students select 11, 'F', 'English'
insert into @students select 12, 'M', 'English'
```

And I need output like this:

```
GroupNo Subj    Gender  StdId
1   English F   8
1   English F   9
2   English F   11
3   English M   10
3   English M   12
4   History F   6
5   History M   7
6   Math    F   1
6   Math    F   4
7   Math    F   5
8   Math    M   2
8   Math    M   3
```

Comment: Great job posting sample date in an easily copied format! Generally, though, it's best to also show us what you've tried and what's not working with it. Otherwise, we're just doing the work for you, and you're not getting the opportunity to learn the code. Check out [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I did up-vote, though, for including the data set up and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found my solution with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656848/t-sql-dense-rank-with-a-maximum-number-of-rows-with-each-rank)

```
;with FirstRank as 
(select DENSE_RANK() over (order by Subj, Gender) as rnk, * from @students),
SecondRank AS
(select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rnk ORDER by gender)-1)
            / 2 as rn,*
    from FirstRank
)
select DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rnk,rn) as GrpNo, Subj, Gender, StdId from SecondRank
```

Comment: Well, since you found a solution I've deleted my answer.